# Getting string tokens / params as parsing

Tags: c++, parsing, token, parameters

I've been trying hard enough to find a way in C++ to get tokens and params in a script file of my own, I can do this in C# using regex and all but I need to do it in C++

Let's say I've this script file:

```
Name = Tywin Lanninster
Age = 35

CustomAttributes = {
 Health = 100,
 Mana = 100,
 Height = 4,
 Weight = 40
}
```

What I need to know about is how to interat through all this code, and trigger between tokens?
Like get Name value, age value, and then get all data inside behavior while also being able to get it's value? It's like being able to parse it, I've boost but Spirit isn't what I'm looking for, I've seen the `std::string` has a `find_first_of` function, so I'm looking for answers.

I've found a question like mine from 2007, but the code given isn't enough as it's incomplete, but can see it's what i'm looking for: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/76797/simple-script-parser-how-to-

Please help me!

So I've made this:

This is my first load loop for parsing:

```
while (getline(file, text)) {
    if (!getNextToken()) continue;
    std::cout << "Token: '" << token << "'" << std::endl;
    if (token == "Name")
    {
        getString();
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Unknown token: '" << token << "'" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The function I use for getting tokens, I'm able to obtain things like Age & Name

```
bool Script::getNextToken()
char letter;

    for (int i = 0; i != text.size(); i++)
    {
        letter = text[i];
        if (letter == TOKEN_EQUAL)
        {
            token = text.substr(0, i-1);
            text.erase(0, i+2);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The code i use for getting strings inside "

```
    bool Script::getString()
    char letter;
    std::string str;
    std::cout << "Trying to get string from: " << text << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i != text.size() + 1; i++)
    {
        letter = text[i];
        if (letter == TOKEN_STRING)
        {
            text.erase(0, 1);
            int pos = text.find_first_of(TOKEN_STRING);
            str = text.substr(i, pos);
            std::cout << "String Found: " << str << std::endl;
            text.erase(pos);
            std::cout << "text left: " << text << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
```

But I've no idea how to get things inside { } since they are in different lines and I'm using getline

Comment: can you use regex in C++11?

Comment: I've boost 1.55, but doing regex would simplify everything and ignore the CustomAttributes token and the { } brackets as if it wasn't a parser.

Comment: I've used regex in C# but I want to interpret and be able to get token by token, like in the link I showed.

Comment: I'm thinking of reading all chars from a std::string in a loop until it's the end of the string, if I hit this token (=) I read everything before this token and read further until a new line or a token specified, any clues about this? This is farther I could simplify my question

Comment: If the grammar you are trying to parse is more complicated than the sample you gave, you should try using tools like [tag:lex] and [tag:yacc]. They are made for the purpose of simplifying lexical and syntactic analysis, and provide good performances.

Comment: Also, you should not dismiss boost spirit: just like the above tools, it is slightly steep a curve to start with, but the pay off is when you want to do modifications to your grammar.

Comment: Regarding your code, you probably want to avoid as much copying as possible, especially on a char by char basis. Ideally, you should keep pointers on your content, and increment decrement them as needed when doing parsing. It's probably better even to rely on the `std` library as much as possible (using iterators on streams), and copy at the last moment, if you need to keep that string around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update:

Given that your file format is tad more complex than what I first thought, I gave it another shot using [boost-spirit](/questions/tagged/boost-spirit) this time. Indeed, it's a tedious enterprise to get it to work with something more complicated than the trivial examples of the tutorial, but with a little help from the stackoverflow entries, I managed to get something working.

Here it goes:

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_object.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

namespace data {

  namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
  namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

  struct custom_attributes {
/*
    custom_attributes(int h = 0, int m = 0, int ht = 0, int w = 0):
      health(h), mana(m), height(ht), weight(w){}
*/
    int health;
    int mana;
    int height;
    int weight;
  };

  struct player {
/*
    player(std::string n="", int a=0, custom_attributes at={}):
      name(n), age(a), attrs(at) {}
*/
    std::string name;
    int age;
    custom_attributes attrs;
  };
}  

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    data::custom_attributes,
    (int, health)
    (int, mana)
    (int, height)
    (int, weight)
)

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    data::player,
    (std::string, name)
    (int, age)
    (data::custom_attributes, attrs)
)

namespace data {
  template <typename Iterator>
  struct attributes_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, custom_attributes(), ascii::space_type> {
    attributes_parser() : attributes_parser::base_type(start) {

      using qi::int_;
      using qi::lit;
      using qi::lexeme;
      using ascii::char_;
      using ascii::space_type;

      start %=
        lit("CustomAttributes")
        >> '=' >> '{'
        >>  lit("Health") >> '=' >> int_ >> ','
        >>  lit("Mana") >> '=' >> int_ >> ','
        >>  lit("Height") >> '=' >> int_ >> ','
        >>  lit("Weight") >> '=' >> int_
        >>  '}'
        ;
    }
    qi::rule<Iterator, custom_attributes(), ascii::space_type> start;
  };

  template <typename Iterator>
  struct player_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, player(), ascii::space_type> {
    player_parser() : player_parser::base_type(start) {
      using qi::int_;
      using qi::lit;
      using qi::lexeme;
      using ascii::char_;
      using ascii::space_type;

      quoted_string %= lexeme[+(char_ - '"')];

      start %=
        lit("Name") >> '=' >> '"' >> quoted_string >> '"' >>
        lit("Age") >> '=' >> int_ >> attributes
        ;
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> quoted_string;
    qi::rule<Iterator, player(), ascii::space_type> start;
    attributes_parser<Iterator> attributes;
    };

}

int main(){

  using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
  typedef boost::spirit::istream_iterator iterator_type;

  typedef data::player_parser<iterator_type> player_parser;
  player_parser g;
  data::player plr;

  std::ifstream in("player.txt");
  in.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

  iterator_type iter(in), end;

  bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, g, space, plr);

  if (r && iter == end){
    std::cout << "parsing succeeded:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  name = " << plr.name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  age = " << plr.age << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    health = " << plr.attrs.health << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    mana = " << plr.attrs.mana << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    height = " << plr.attrs.height << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    weight = " << plr.attrs.weight << std::endl;
    
  } else {
    std::cout << "parsing failed" << std::endl;

  }
}
```

A few points:

I used version 1.49 of boost for this.

The above code works on the sample provided in the question, if stored in a file (aptly named `player.txt`) , and *with double quotes around strings which are meant to be values*, and not keywords, as for instance the value for the *Name* attribute.

I chose to split the grammar in two, so that you could reuse and extend the attribute section. It seems to be a reasonable guess as to where you'll be headed next. However, it means that support for [boost-fusion](/questions/tagged/boost-fusion) *serialization* will be difficult. There are entries on stackoverflow dealing with that issue. Please check'em out, and ask again if there's a problem.

---

Old answer:

Since you want to use regex, I suppose that the document's grammar is quite simple, and you wish to read it line by line. Furthermore, the sample you present in your question can be tokenized with spaces or carriage returns as separators.

you could simply use iostream and the `>>` operator, and a set of combinators (ie. functions doing each a simple operation, that you combine to produce more complex ones) for each line format.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::istream;
using std::vector;

class parse_exn : public std:runtime_error{
    public:
        parse_exn(const string msg) : runtime_error(msg){}
};

bool expect(istream &is, const string atom){
    string data;
    Is >> data;
    return is.good() && data == atom; // or throw
}

int readAttribute(istream &is, const string name){
    int result;
    if (expect(is, name) && expect(is,"="))
        is >> result;
        If (is.good())
            return result;
    }
    throw parse_exn("invalid attribute");
}

 Yourclass readStruct(istream &is, const vector<string> attributes){
    // parse header (name, "=","{")
    // parse each attribute and commas
    // parse footer ("}")
    // return the object
    // or throw an exn if something got wrong
}
```

`Yourclass` is supposed to be a class you defined which contains the data you parsed. You should get the idea. Now *please try writing something and come back if you get stuck*.

Note: *above code untested*.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Heere's what I've made:
`

Comment: Apparently, the grammar is more complex than what it seems. The above code won't do.

Comment: Hello, I'm shocked this could be done using Boost! And seems to be just what I need, but is it working? For a reason I'm only getting the name attribute value, not age neither custom attributes. If I could tell what is wrong I could work my way from here!

Comment: I tested my code with your data, with only one difference: I put double quotes around the name. You could definitely change that and have it look for 2 words instead there, if you think this will be the only pattern.

Comment: It isn't working for me, I'm using the same data from the sample and added the quotes around the name value, it says it parsed successfully but for a reason I ain't getting custom attributes neither age values, only name - And I literally copy pasted it since I've never used Boost::Qi before.

Comment: Also note that [tag:boost-spirit] is based on regexes, so it is somewhat close to what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Well, that's strange. Maybe something changed since 1.49?

Comment: For some reason it is working using old Boost libs from 2010 I had saved around my hard drive, thanks for your help didn't know this was possible with Boost

Comment: Ah, actually, I solved it with this version! In my eagerness to get rid of boost fusion because serialization didn't work, I didn't realize that it was actually *necessary* to get it to work at all! Now fixed. Sorry for the confusion.